# BIOS with 'no issue UEFICompliant' support for GPT partition tables

Tags: boot, partitioning, bios, mbr, gpt

I would like to change my hard drive partition table from MBR to GPT,

(since MBR supports 4 primary partitions).

After some searching, I discovered `C:\Windows\Panther\setupacl.log`, and found a few interesting lines.

**3 lines of interest:**

> **1.** Callback_BootEnvironmentDetect: Detected boot environment: BIOS

Meaning of BIOS / UEFI, I am using the old bios : BIOS

> **2.** ConX::Compatibility::CSystemAbstraction::HostIsUEFIFirmware: Host is not UEFI.

Obviously I am not UEFI

**And the particular line of interest**

> **3.** CHostIsUEFICompliantChecker: checked HostIsUEFICompliant, found NoIssue.

Since UEFI supports GPT and MBR, but does MBR support GPT?

I am curios to whether I am able to change to a GPT partition table with my current bios:BIOS and still be able to boot?

Answer (score 0):

> Obviously I am not UEFI

Not really. If your UEFI firmware has decided to boot the OS in BIOS-compatibility (CSM) mode, it'll also look like BIOS. It would be more reliable to look through the firmware's settings screen or documentation.

Also, when you try to boot from a CD or USB through the firmware's "boot menu", look carefully – often there will be *two* entries for booting a CD; one for UEFI mode and one for BIOS CSM mode.

(Also, if you're making a Windows installation USB yourself, be careful with unofficial tools. For example, Rufus will let you choose between making an UEFI-compatible and BIOS-only USB, while WinUSB doesn't support UEFI at all.)

> but does MBR support GPT?

That question doesn't make sense.

> I am curios to whether I am able to change to a GPT partition table with my current bios:BIOS and still be able to boot?

This is technically possible, assuming…

1. …the BIOS supports it. Normally BIOS shouldn't care at all – it should just run the OS's bootcode from 0th sector and let *that* parse partitions on its own, whether they be in MBR or GPT.

   Unfortunately *some* BIOSes insist on having valid partitions in the MBR. And some will outright crash if they find a GPT. I guess you'll have to try and see.
2. …the OS and its bootloader supports it. Linux can boot from such a combination just fine, but as far as I know, Windows cannot. (That is, Windows wants either UEFI+GPT or BIOS+MBR.)